# Добавить значение в ячейку MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. В админпанели сайта реализован функционал массового присвоения категорий списку элементов, который заменяет текущее значение категорий для выбранного списка на новое. Как сделать так чтобы функция добавляла новые значения к старым, а не заменяла их? К примеру есть 5 элементов которые находятся в категории А, как сделать чтобы при добавлений категорий В и С мы получили все три А В С . Ниже прилагаю код, который выполняет процесс массовой ассоциации категорий к выбранным элементам. (извиняюсь за дилетантскую формулировку). Спасибо

```
   public function massxref_cats(){
    $this->massxref('massxref');
}

public function massxref_cats_exe(){

    $virtuemart_cat_ids = vRequest::getInt('cid', array() );

    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $cids = json_decode($session->get('vm_product_ids', array(), 'vm'),true);

    $productModel = VmModel::getModel('product');
    foreach($cids as $cid){
        $data = array('virtuemart_product_id' => $cid, 'virtuemart_category_id' => $virtuemart_cat_ids);
        $data = $productModel->updateXrefAndChildTables ($data, 'product_categories',TRUE);
    }

    $this->massxref('massxref_cats');
}

public function massxref($layoutName){

    vRequest::vmCheckToken();

    $cids = vRequest::getInt('virtuemart_product_id');

    if(empty($cids)){
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $cids = json_decode($session->get('vm_product_ids', '', 'vm'),true);
    } else {
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $session->set('vm_product_ids', json_encode($cids),'vm');
    }

    if(!empty($cids)){
        $q = 'SELECT `product_name` FROM `#__virtuemart_products_' . VmConfig::$vmlang . '` ';
        $q .= ' WHERE `virtuemart_product_id` IN (' . implode(',', $cids) . ')';

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $db->setQuery($q);

        $productNames = $db->loadColumn();

        vmInfo('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_XREF_NAMES',implode(', ',$productNames));
    }

    $this->addViewPath(VMPATH_ADMIN . DS . 'views');
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $viewType = $document->getType();
    $view = $this->getView($this->_cname, $viewType);

    $view->setLayout($layoutName);

    $view->display();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В случае, когда есть множество элементов, которые имеют 1 и более категорий, и когда одна категория может содержать множество связанных с ней элементов, лучше всего использовать соединение "многие-ко-многим". Для этого создается связная таблица, например, elements_categories с двумя первичными ключами в виде element_id и category_id, куда заносится id элемента и id категории. А потом запросами достается нужный элемент со связанными с ним категориями. В этом случае, при добавлении новых элементов со своими категориями старые удаляться не будут, ибо каждое значение в таблице elements_categories будет уникальным.

Comment: дело в том, что функционал мульткатегорий реализован. При редактировании отдельного элемента можно именно добавить сколько угодно категорий к нему. При массовой ассоциации для списка элемента можно также добавить сколько угодно категорий, но в этом случае заменяются предыдущие значения. Я думаю что все кроится в данном коде, который я представила, но могу ошибаться так как не сильна в этом (выполняется что то типа path, а надо update :))

Comment: функционалом этого экшена предусмотрено присвоение множества категорий, но очень важно, чтобы значения добавлялись а не заменялись. спасибо.

Comment: @Anna Это проблематично так как, вам надо делать селект выбирать старые значения и дописывать, при редактирование отдельного элемента на фронте выбрана категория к которой он пренадлежит, т.е. функционал обновляет строку но полностью.

Comment: @Naumov жаль :(  но ведь так как вы сказали (или возможно каким-то образом иначе) такой функционал присутствует при редактировании каждого элемента по отдельности, может можно и в массовую ассоциацию его прикрутить

Comment: @Naumov может нужно попробовать отыскать код редактирования категорий отдельного элемента и в студию его ?

Comment: @Anna дело в том что редактирование одного элемента и множества скорее всего выполняет один код